# Rails 3 - How to send data on link_to :remote=>true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to, link-to-remote

I am trying to figure out the new `link_to` in `Rails 3` but i still don't get it
In Rails 2 I do:

```
<%= link_to_remote "My Link",:url=>{:action=>:myaction},:with=>"'data='+$('#someField').attr('value')" %>
```

but with the new syntax in Rails 3 how should it be?

I'm trying something like

```
<%=link_to "My Link",{:action=>"myaction"},:with=>"'data='+$('#someField').attr('value');",:remote=>true%>
```

but I'm not getting the quantity params in the controller's action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They say its no longer supported in this answer on [How to send Javascript Variable to a controller's action with the link_to helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875448/rails3-how-to-send-javascript-variable-to-a-controllers-action-with-the-link-t/5875634#5875634)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this will send a "data" parameter with the value = 10.

```
link_to "My Link", { :controller => 'myctrler', :action=>"myact", :data=> 10 }, :remote=>true
```

I've never seen/used the :with option before. I'm sorry I can't help on that one.

Comment: Still don't get `data` in the params i just get `{"controller"=>"myController", "action"=>"myAction"}`

Comment: The first hash is entirely used for the url. See http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M006564

Comment: This one works and send the value `10` for the `data` parameter but it's not working for me i want to get a value from a field or a variable from javascript when the link is clicked and sen this to my controller's action

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add the variable with the value in the path url, for example:

```
<%= link_to "SEND DATA", "server_function?myData=10", remote: true %>
```

and if you need to send more than one parameter you must to use `&` for example `?myData=10&myOtherData=12`, where the params are `myData` with the value of 10 and `myOtherData` with 12.

Comment: It'd be better if I only use `<%=link_to "sen data", {:controller=>:my_controller, :action=>:my_action, :data=>10, :other_param => "foo"}%>` but way i was trying to do here was sending javascript variables through a remote link and now that's not possible on rails 3 as it was on rails two using the `with` parameter.