# Rails3 - How to send Javascript Variable to a controller's action with the link_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to, link-to-remote

If i have the following javascript code

```
var myVar = 0;

function setNewValforVar(newValue){
    myVar = newValue;
}
```

and i'm calling `setNewValforVar` function `n` times

so when I click on a link it'd send `myVar` value to the controller action in a remote link like

```
<%=link_to "My Link",{:action=>"myAction"},:data=>''sval='+myVar',:remote=>true%>
```

I Rails 2.3.x I'd do this with

```
<%=link_to_remote "My Link",:url=>{:action=>"myAction"},:with=>"'sval='+myVar"%>
```

and i was getting this on the controller's action with

```
params["myVar"]
```

how do I do this on Rails 3 with the `link_to` helper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 3 no longer supports this behavior. You will have to either create a form to submit the value, or modify the `href` of the link to include the value in the query string.

Comment: I Had to do a function call in the `onclick` method and a `remote_function` inside of this... which it's still supporting the behavior, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found some solution that use callbacks. Link must be marked in some way, for example by adding the `id`:

```
<%=link_to "My Link", {:action=>"myAction"}, :remote=>true, :id => "mylink" %>
```

There is an example for `prototype_ujs`: the parameter is simply appended to the request's URL (the code is a bit simplified I assume that some parameters already exist).

```
<%= javascript_tag("document.on('ajax:create', 'a#mylink',
      function(event) { event.memo.request.url += '&sval=' + myVar; })") %>
```

Some advantage of this (ugly a bit) solution is the possibility of using one function for a particular class of links instead of the indicated id.