# Ruby on rails add javascript variable to link_to url params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a javascript variable, I would to send along with my params when a person clicks a link.

```
var js_variable = something;
...
<%= link_to_remote "Link Name", {:url => {url_params}, ajax_options}, {html_options} %>
```

how do I add js_variable to the url_params hash??

Using rails 2.3.8

Comment: doesn't matter.... could be a string, int, whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly this older question will be useful to you [Rails3 - How to send Javascript Variable to a controller's action with the link_to helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875448/rails3-how-to-send-javascript-variable-to-a-controllers-action-with-the-link-t/5875634#5875634)

But it seems to me you should be using `link_to_function` and change the href at runtime

Comment: I'm using rails 2, probs should have said that.

Comment: there is a ralis 2 example =D

Comment: yeah I should have made it more clear in the comment that there was rails2 code in it :)