# ajax call pass javascript variable in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
<script> var depart_date='11 February 2013';
         var depart_date='21 February 2013';


    jQuery.ajax({

data: { depart: depart_date, return_date: return_date},
    type: 'post',
  url: "/payment/create",

});
```

This is my ajax call.

In terminal it's value getting as {"depart"=>"11 February 2013", "return_date"=>"21 February 2013"}

But in controller params[:depart] & params[:return_date] shows as nil value.

Don't know where i am doing mistake..

Comment: If you are getting values in terminal then you are all right. The only thing is: its `params[:return_date]` and not `params[:return]`. The second thing is, you ended the script before ajax function.

Comment: @ Saurabh Jain thanks for this checking. but params[:depart] also shows nil.

Comment: Check my answer below and see what it gives for both.

Comment: in terminal it is passing as {"depart"=>"11 February 2013", "return_date"=>"21 February 2013"}.but when i try to get in controller as params[:depart] &params[:return_date].both returns 'nil'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change depart_date to return_date and end the script at the end as:

```
<script> 

   var depart_date='11 February 2013';
   var return_date='21 February 2013';

        jQuery.ajax({

    data: { depart: depart_date, return_date: return_date},
        type: 'post',
      url: "/payment/create",

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Make sure that you defined your `params[:depart]` and `params[:return_date]` in your create method of payments controller. Also check what is the value for `params[:return_date]`.

Comment: @depart=params[:depart]
@return=params[:return_date]                                      this is my code in controller

Comment: if it is possible to pass Js variable using link_to in rails 3 pls suggest me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875448/rails3-how-to-send-javascript-variable-to-a-controllers-action-with-the-link